# how to pass get method method in curl array

Tags: php, curl

I'm using url to pass row data from one page to another

```
echo "<td >
    <a href='sessiondetails.php?docname={$key['DocName']}& HosName={$key['HosName']}& HosCode={$key['HosCode']}............}'>
       More>>
    </a></font>
    </td>
</tr>";
```

In my second page I am using `$_GET` to assign the values to variables and echoing is working good.
But when I assign the variable as array value it does not pass the value, I can't understand why.

Here is my second page code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='style1.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <?php
        $SpecializationId = $_GET['SpecialitionID'];
        $DoctorNo         = $_GET['DoctorNo'] ;
        $day              = $_GET['day'];
        $date             = $_GET['date']; 
        $HosCode          = $_GET['HosCode'];       
        $hospital         = $_GET['HosName'];
        $doctor           = $_GET['docname'];
        $specialization   = $_GET['SpecName'];

        $baseurl = 'http://202.124.173.187/api/v1/doctorSessions';    
        $rawPOSTdata = array(
            "hosID"  => $HosCode,
            "specID" => $SpecializationId,
            "docNo"  => $DoctorNo,
            "day"    => $day,
            "date"   => $date 
        );

        $curl = curl_init($baseurl);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
             'Content-Type: application/json',
             "Authorization: Bearer $atoken"
        )); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($rawPOSTdata));    
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        if($response) {
            if (isset($result->error) ) die( $result->error_message );
            /* Convert json data to array */

            $arr=json_decode( $response,true);
    ?>
```

`"hosID"=>$hosCode,` is not taking value

Comment: Why do you have a space between the & and the variable in the URL params? Also, have you tried var_dump($HosCode) to see if it has anything?

Comment: Remove spaces from url and check `var_dump($_GET)` to see what you are passing

Comment: Also, I assume the "............}" isn't in the actual code.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not escaping the GET variables properly, nor are you encoding it for HTML properly, and you're probably getting a data corruption here. to escape it properly, use `http_build_query` to make your url, and html encode it with  `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars`, like this

```
echo '<td >
    <a href="sessiondetails.php?'.htmlentities(http_build_query(array('docname'=>$key['DocName'],'HosName'=>$key['HosName'],'HosCode'=>$key['HosCode'])),ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED,'UTF-8',true).'">
       More>>
    </a></font>
    </td>
</tr>';
```

in the future, you can use https://validator.w3.org/ to detect when you're not properly encoding variables to HTML, and would probably have detected your error here

Comment: Than you for the help its wk